# Set a current row in a dataframe based off of future values

Tags: python, pandas

Given:

```py
    d = {
    'datetime': ['2010-01-08 09:45:00', '2010-01-08 10:00:00',
               '2010-01-08 10:15:00', '2010-01-08 10:30:00',
               '2010-01-08 10:45:00', '2010-01-08 11:00:00',
               '2010-01-08 11:15:00', '2010-01-08 11:30:00',
               '2010-01-08 11:45:00', '2010-01-08 12:00:00',
               '2010-01-08 12:15:00', '2010-01-08 12:30:00',
               '2010-01-08 12:45:00', '2010-01-08 13:00:00',
               '2010-01-08 13:15:00', '2010-01-08 13:30:00',
               '2010-01-08 13:45:00', '2010-01-08 14:00:00',
               '2010-01-08 14:15:00', '2010-01-08 14:30:00',
               '2010-01-08 14:45:00', '2010-01-08 15:00:00',
               '2010-01-08 15:15:00', '2010-01-08 15:30:00',
               '2010-01-08 15:45:00', '2010-01-08 16:00:00',
               '2010-01-08 16:15:00'],
    'Total-tops': [0,-1,-1,2,3,0,0,4,0,0,0,0,5,6,7,8,-1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1,-1,2]
}

df = pandas.DataFrame(d)
df = df.set_index('datetime')
```

I want to add another column which is a boolean for whether that row will break or not. A break means the tops are at a number greater than 1 and then a -1 occurs somewhere in the future. For example the first 2 will break at the next -1 it encounters. Here is the desired dataframe:
[image: desired_dataframe]

Here is the function I am currently using, but it runs very slow, since I iterate over all rows.

```py
def does_break(data):
    cur_breaks = []

    for index, row in data.iterrows():
        if row['Total-tops'] > 1:
            # Get all rows after this time that are new tops
            breaks = data[(data['Total-tops'] == -1) & (data.index.time > index.time())]
            if len(breaks) > 0:
                cur_breaks.append(True)
            else:
                cur_breaks.append(False)
        else:
            cur_breaks.append(False)
    return cur_breaks
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
latest_break = df.index[(df['Total-tops'] == -1)].max()
df['break'] = 1
df['break'] = df['break'].where((df['Total-tops'] > 0) & (df.index < latest_break), 0)
```

Set break to 1 for all positive values that occur before the latest break

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ungainly expression

```
In [56]: import numpy as np

In [57]: ((np.cumsum((df['Total-tops'] == -1)[:: -1])[:: -1] > 0) & (df['Total-tops'] > 0)).astype(int)
Out[57]: 
datetime
2010-01-08 09:45:00    0
2010-01-08 10:00:00    0
2010-01-08 10:15:00    0
2010-01-08 10:30:00    1
2010-01-08 10:45:00    1
2010-01-08 11:00:00    0
2010-01-08 11:15:00    0
2010-01-08 11:30:00    1
2010-01-08 11:45:00    0
2010-01-08 12:00:00    0
2010-01-08 12:15:00    0
2010-01-08 12:30:00    0
2010-01-08 12:45:00    1
2010-01-08 13:00:00    1
2010-01-08 13:15:00    1
2010-01-08 13:30:00    1
2010-01-08 13:45:00    0
2010-01-08 14:00:00    0
2010-01-08 14:15:00    0
2010-01-08 14:30:00    0
2010-01-08 14:45:00    0
2010-01-08 15:00:00    0
2010-01-08 15:15:00    0
2010-01-08 15:30:00    0
2010-01-08 15:45:00    0
2010-01-08 16:00:00    0
2010-01-08 16:15:00    0
Name: Total-tops, dtype: int64
```

(Of course, for your new column, you can use `df['breaks'] = ...`.)

What this does is as follows:

1. We find where the values are -1, and reverse. Now any operations we do on the past (in particular `cumsum`), is really performed on the future.
2. We find the cumulative sum, and reverse again. At this point, the meaning is how many times in the future will we see a -1.
3. We find where the result is larger than 0, since we don't care *how many times* will we see a -1, only *whether* we will see it.
4. Finally, we also require that the current entry is positive. This is just the definition from your question.